# Does Such Mechanical Keyboards Exist?

Tags: keyboards

I have been searching a mechanical keyboard with following features for a very long time. Many major players I checked in the market have some of the features, but none have them all. I figure there must be a manufacturer combines them together.

- "Open" Design. Like Corsaire K70, I want a borderless keyboard for convenient cleaning. A blow of wind should be able to pass through from one end of the keyboard to another.
- 2+ USB/audio passthrough. I have seen similar designs in Razer and Daskeyboard. The former brand offers 1 USB and 1 audio port while the latter offers 2 USB ports. Both are good.
- Tactile switch. I prefer Cherry MX blue. But similar switches are also welcomed. I.e. Razer Green Switch.
- Dedicated Media keys for volume control and playback. No keybindings needed, such as Fn + F12 is not good.

Thank you.

Comment: What size? Full size, TLK, 60%, 40%?

Comment: Good question. It would be best if it is full size or TLK. I do need quick access to home,delete,end,pg up, pg dn.

Comment: Razer has a few but they're Greentech switches, not Cherry. I'm going to keep looking.

Comment: Personally, I find the Code Keyboard's media controls to be easy to use one handed.  I think it's odd to get dedicated media keys on a mechanical keyboard and have the media keys of inferior quality (i.e. not rated for millions of key presses) to the usual keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far I've only been able to find two keyboards that fit the bill. I don't have a particular recommendation of one over the other–they both are from decent but not excellent brands, use slightly funky layouts, are fairly pricy, and look (IMO) fairly poor–but neither are particularly bad options, and I'd recommend you choose on personal preference.

#### [G.Skill KM780 MX](https://www.gskill.com/en/product/ripjaws-km780-mx--cherry-mx-blue) - [$103.67](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/4ntWGX/gskill-keyboard-gkksr1c2km780s10na) / [KM780R MX](https://www.gskill.com/en/product/ripjaws-km780r-mx--cherry-mx-blue) - [$83.20](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/w2mxFT/gskill-keyboard-gkksr1c2km780rs10na) / KM780R MX RGB - [$129.99](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/cntWGX/gskill-keyboard-gkkcl1c2km780rs10na)

[image]

#### [Cougar 700k](http://cougargaming.com/products/keyboards/700k/) - [$117.79](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/cM8H99/cougar-keyboard-kbc7003is)

[image]